# Replacing a character in only one column in multiple files (inside a folder)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder which contains XLSX file (TDMS file converted to XLSX).
I want to replace comma by dot in column A.
The data in column A have the following format : 2020/06/12 16:07:12,465
I want the format to change to be like this : 2020/06/12 16:07:12.465
In order to plot the data stored in these files using software like DatPlot or KstPlot to process data faster than Excel could do.

I used the record macro to get a working macro that does the job when I call it with a button located directly on the same sheet that I want to modify.

```
Sub Comma_by_Dot()
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="*,*", Replacement:="*.*", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

But I want to modify multiple files that are located in the same folder automatically using VBA.
Currently I'm using this code without much result :

```
Sub ReplaceCommabyDot_folder()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim InputFile As Variant
Dim InputFolder As String, OutputFolder As String, myfile As String
Dim wbSource As Workbook

InputFolder = "C:\test"
OutputFolder = "C:\test"

'Loop through each file in source folder
InputFile = Dir(InputFolder & "\*.xlsx")

While InputFile <> ""
    myfile = InputFolder & "\" & InputFile
    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(myfile)
    Columns("A").Replace What:="*,*", Replacement:="*.*", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

'Save each output file in output folder
wbSource.SaveAs Filename:=myfile, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault, local:=True
Workbooks(InputFile).Close

InputFile = Dir
Wend

End Sub
```

The second VBA code doesn't work as I intended because it doesn't change the comma by a dot in column A.
It saves and overwrites all my files in the folder but doesn't apply change to column A.

I guess I'm doing something wrong but I have looked on internet and can't figure out what I'm not doing the right way.

Comment: `Columns("A").Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart`  Also you don't need SaveAs - just close and save the original file.

Comment: Is the data in ColumnA formatted that way but really the underlying value is a date, or it it that literal text  (eg) " 2020/06/12 16:07:12,465"  ?  If you open a file what is the numberformat in ColA?

Comment: The data format in column A is text. Maybe Excel interpret this as a date. What do you mean by I don't need saveAs ? How do I save my file then ? If I just close it, it won't save it no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem to convert XLSX file to CSV with the proper formatting I wanted for the Time column (column A).

I did it in Python since Excel wasn't doing the job correctly using VBA.

Here is the Python code that successfully convert XLSX which were initially TDMS file to CSV file for plotting in DatPlot or whatever plotting tool you want to use :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
import pandas as pd

root = tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300, bg='lightsteelblue2', relief='raised')
canvas1.pack()

label1 = tk.Label(root, text='File Conversion Tool', bg='lightsteelblue2')
label1.config(font=('helvetica', 20))
canvas1.create_window(150, 60, window=label1)

read_file = pd.DataFrame()


def get_excel():
    global read_file
    import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    read_file = pd.read_excel(import_file_path)
    read_file['Time'] = read_file['Time'].str.replace(',', '.')
    tk.messagebox.showinfo(title="Import success", message="XLSX file import successful !")


def saveas_csv():
    global read_file
    export_file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.csv')
    read_file.to_csv(export_file_path, index=None, header=True, decimal=',', sep=';')


browseButton_Excel = tk.Button(text="Import Excel File", command=get_excel, bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(150, 130, window=browseButton_Excel)

saveAsButton_CSV = tk.Button(text='Convert Excel to CSV', command=saveas_csv, bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(150, 180, window=saveAsButton_CSV)

root.mainloop()
```

Now it works as I wanted and the time column isn't modified in any way as it should after replacing the comma by dot in the string : 2020/06/12 17:40:59,290 (data in time column)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your findings with SO :D

Answer (score 1):

When you write `Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(myfile)`, myfile becomes the active workbook.  The active worksheet will be whichever worksheet was active when the workbook was last saved.

You next write `Columns("A").Replace ...` .  This statement operates on the active worksheet.  If the wrong worksheet is active, this statement will not have the effect you seek.

If my guess about the cause of your problem is correct, try `Worksheets("xxx").Columns("A").Replace ...`  where "xxx" is the name of the worksheet containing the column you wish to change.

**Edit 1**

I find it difficult to understand what is going wrong.  You say the name of the worksheet is “Values” but when you try to access that worksheet you are told it does not exist.  I will try to explain `Workbooks`, `Worksheets` and related terms.

Suppose you open workbooks “A.xlsx”, “B.xlsx” and “C.xlsm”.  It is possible to open “A.xlsx”, “B.xlsx” and “C.xlsm” each in their own copy (instance) of Excel.exe, but this is not easy.  Normally, there will be one instance of Excel.exe “containing” three open workbooks.  `Workbooks` is a collection or list of the open workbooks within an instance of Excel..  A macro within “C.xlsm” could contain:

```
Dim InxWbk As Long

For InxWbk = 1 to Workbooks.Count
  Debug.Print Workbooks(InxWbk).Name
Next
```

If you run this block of code, you will get the following output:

```
A.xlsx
B.xlsx
C.xlsm
```

In the above code, I have accessed the workbooks as `Workbooks(1)`, `Workbooks(2)` and `Workbooks(3)`.  I could also have written `Workbooks("B.xlsx")`.  If you know about arrays, a collection is like an array except I can add a new entry to a collection at the beginning, in the middle or the end and I can identify an entry by its position (1, 2 or 3) or by its key ("A.xlsx", "B.xlsx", "C.xlsm").

If I had written `Workbooks(4)` or `Workbooks("D.xlsx")`, I would get error “Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range” because there is no `Workbooks(4)` or `Workbooks("D.xlsx")`.

If I write:

```
Workbooks.Open("D.xlsx")
```

This will open a new workbook and add a new entry to the `Workbooks` collection.  Now `Workbooks(4)` or `Workbooks("D.xlsx")` will not give an error.

Each workbook has a collection named `Worksheets` which contains all the worksheets within the workbook.  I can write:

```
Dim InxWsht As Long

For InxWsht = 1 to Worksheets.Count
  Debug.Print Worksheets(InxWsht).Name
Next
```

If you run this code, you will get a list of the worksheets within a workbook.  But which workbook?  My code does not specify a workbook, so Excel selects the workbook for me.  With code like this, it will always select the **active** workbook.  When, I opened my three workbooks, whichever one I opened last is the active workbook.  When my code reaches `Workbooks.Open("D.xlsx")`, “D.xlsx” becomes the active workbook.  I can also write:

```
Workbooks("B.xlsx").Activate
```

In your code you write `Columns("A").Replace …`.  You are relying on the workbook you have just opened being the active workbook.  This can get very confusing if you have several workbooks.  It is always better to be explicit.  I would write:

```
 Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(myfile)
 With wbSource
    With .Worksheets("Values")
      .Columns("A").Replace What:="*,*", Replacement:="*.*", LookAt:=xlPart, _
          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
          ReplaceFormat:=False
    End With
  .Close SaveChanges:=True
End With
```

`With wbSource` tells Excel which workbook I wish to use.

The dot in front of `.Worksheets("Values")` tells Excel I want to use a worksheet within the workbook specified by the `With wbSource` statement .

The dot in from of `Columns` tells Excel I want to use a column within the workbook specified by the `With .Worksheets("Values")` statement .

I use `End With` to end `With .Worksheets("Values")` so `.Close` is within `With wbSource` .

If this is all new to you, it is probably confusing.  But I hope you can see that, with the correct indenting, it becomes easy for someone with only a little experience of `With` to quickly see which workbook or worksheet is being accessed.

I did not need to use `With`.  I could have written:

```
wbSource.Worksheets("Values").Columns("A").Replace _
          What:="*,*", Replacement:="*.*", LookAt:=xlPart, _
          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
          ReplaceFormat:=False
```

I prefer nested `With`s most of the time but your preference may be different.

Note: as Tim wrote in his comment, you should use `Close` not `SaveAs` to save the amended workbook.  I have never tried using `SaveAs` instead of `Close` but I imagine you would be asked if the old workbook is to be overwritten for each `SaveAs`.

When you wrote `Worksheets(Ws.Name).Columns("A").Replace …`, you got error “Object variable or With block variable not set”.  You used `Dim Ws as Worksheet` to specify
Ws as a worksheet but you never gave it a value.  You omitted `Set Ws = .Worksheets("Values")`.

I hope the above gives you an understanding of what is happening when you access `Columns` or `Worksheets`.   It may take a couple of readings and you my find it helpful to try some of the code I show.

Returning to your problem.  You say you get “Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range” when you try to access `Worksheets("Values")`.  You do not say if this error was with the first workbook or after a few successful changes.  Either way, it suggests you are incorrect when you say the worksheet is always named “Values”.  I would try:

```
  Dim InxWsht As Long

  Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(myfile)
 With wbSource
   Debug.Print wbSource.Name
   For InxWsht = 1 to .Worksheets.Count
     Debug.Print .Worksheets(InxWsht).Name
   Next
    With .Worksheets("Values")
      .Columns("A").Replace What:="*,*", Replacement:="*.*", LookAt:=xlPart, _
          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
          ReplaceFormat:=False
    End With
    .Close SaveChanges:=True
  End With
```

If your code stops on the `With .Worksheets("Values")` statement, the Immediate Window will tell you which workbook was open at the time and what worksheets is contains.  This should help you diagnose your problem.

**Edit 2**

I do not understand how you can get the results you report.

I live in Britain, so my version of Excel has dot as the decimal symbol.  Since your package converts with a comma as the decimal symbol, I assume your country uses comma as the decimal symbol so your version of Excel will also use comma.

You do not say how you converted TMDS files to XLSX files.  When a string is imported to Excel, it is sometimes checked to be a number or a date and, if it is, converted to that format.  I am sure the following are strings even if they are valid dates for your version of Excel:

```
2020/06/12 20:23:32,762
2020/06/12 20:23:32,961
2020/06/12 20:23:33,066
2020/06/12 20:23:33,170
2020/06/12 20:23:33,275
2020/06/12 20:23:33,378
2020/06/12 20:23:33,478
2020/06/12 20:23:33,578
```

They are definitely strings in Britain and I cannot get Excel to display seconds to three decimals places so I assume they are strings with your version of Excel.

After you replace the commas with dots, you get:

```
2020/06/12 20:23:32.762
2020/06/12 20:23:32.961
2020/06/12 20:23:33.066
2020/06/12 20:23:33.170
2020/06/12 20:23:33.275
2020/06/12 20:23:33.378
2020/06/12 20:23:33.478
2020/06/12 20:23:33.578
```

I can only get this display if the values are strings.  Excel will **hold** seconds to three decimal places, but it will not **display** to three decimal places.

The following is what happens on my system.

The following values are held as strings since Excel does not recognise them as dates:

```
2020/06/12 20:23:32,762
2020/06/12 20:23:32,961
2020/06/12 20:23:33,066
2020/06/12 20:23:33,170
2020/06/12 20:23:33,275
2020/06/12 20:23:33,378
2020/06/12 20:23:33,478
2020/06/12 20:23:33,578
```

If I replace the commas with dots, I get:

```
23:32.8
23:33.0
23:33.1
23:33.2
23:33.3
23:33.4
23:33.5
23:33.6
```

My guess is that Excel realises these values are now dates and applies the best available date format.  The only standard format with decimal seconds is “mm:ss.0” which is the format used.

If you format the column as “yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss.ss”, you get:

```
2020/06/12 20:23:33.33
2020/06/12 20:23:33.33
2020/06/12 20:23:33.33
2020/06/12 20:23:33.33
2020/06/12 20:23:33.33
2020/06/12 20:23:33.33
2020/06/12 20:23:33.33
2020/06/12 20:23:34.34
```

If I try “yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss.sss”, it is changed to “yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss.ss”.

Although these values are only displayed to two decimal places, they are held to three decimal places as demonstrated by the following:

```
Row|           A          |          B          |        C       |    D    |           E           |
   |----------------------+---------------------+----------------+---------+-----------------------|
  1|2020/06/12 20:23:33.33|43,994.84968474540000|0.84968474537163|73412.762|2020/06/12 20:23:32,762|
   |----------------------+---------------------+----------------+---------+-----------------------|
  2|2020/06/12 20:23:33.33|43,994.84968704860000|0.84968704861240|73412.961|2020/06/12 20:23:32,961|
   |----------------------+---------------------+----------------+---------+-----------------------|
  3|2020/06/12 20:23:33.33|43,994.84968826390000|0.84968826388649|73413.066|2020/06/12 20:23:33,066|
   |----------------------+---------------------+----------------+---------+-----------------------|
  4|2020/06/12 20:23:33.33|43,994.84968946760000|0.84968946759182|73413.170|2020/06/12 20:23:33,170|
   |----------------------+---------------------+----------------+---------+-----------------------|
  5|2020/06/12 20:23:33.33|43,994.84969068290000|0.84969068287319|73413.275|2020/06/12 20:23:33,275|
   |----------------------+---------------------+----------------+---------+-----------------------|
  6|2020/06/12 20:23:33.33|43,994.84969187500000|0.84969187500246|73413.378|2020/06/12 20:23:33,378|
   |----------------------+---------------------+----------------+---------+-----------------------|
  7|2020/06/12 20:23:33.33|43,994.84969303240000|0.84969303241087|73413.478|2020/06/12 20:23:33,478|
   |----------------------+---------------------+----------------+---------+-----------------------|
  8|2020/06/12 20:23:34.34|43,994.84969418980000|0.84969418981200|73413.578|2020/06/12 20:23:33,578|
   |----------------------+---------------------+----------------+---------+-----------------------|
```

Column A contains the values created by the replacement of comma by dot displayed with format “yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss.ss”.

Column B holds the same values (Cell B1, for example, holds =A1) but displayed with format “#,##0.00000000000000”.   Excel holds Dates as Doubles with the integer part being days since 1 January 1900 and the fraction part being seconds-since-midnight divided by seconds-in-a day.

Column C holds the values from Column B with the integer part removed.

Column D holds the values from Column C multiplied by 24 x 60 x 60.  That is, it converts the fraction into seconds since midnight.

Column E holds the original values.  Note, the decimal values in Columns D and E are the same.

I have placed your example values in a single workbook, so my code does not include the code to find and save workbooks.  Replace the central part of your code with my code and you should get the desired result.

```
With Worksheets("Values")
  With .Columns(1)
    .Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    .NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss.ss"
  End With
End With
```

Comment: I tried what you say and changed the line to Worksheets(InputFile).Columns("A").Replace What:="*,*", Replacement:="*.*", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

Comment: But now I got an error because I only changed this line Column("A").Replace to Worksheets(InputFile).Columns("A").Replace

Comment: The error I got is : Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Comment: Do I need to remove the line set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(myfile)

Comment: Because the variable myfile contains the path to the XLSX file including the file name and extension. InputFile is just the file name with extension.

Comment: @gamer388.  In `Worksheets("xxx")`, "xxx" must be the name of the worksheet.  It is not the name of the workbook unless they are the same.  If the worksheet name is not fixed, I can suggest how to determine the correct name.

Comment: The error "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range" is because there is no worksheet InputFile.

Comment: `Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(myfile) ` is the statement that opens `myfile` so you can access it.  It is a necessary statement that cannot be removed.

Comment: I am assuming that column A contains strings.  That is "2020/06/12 16:07:12,465" is a string and not a date formatted to display as "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss,sss".

Comment: Yes the format of the data in column A is text. Oh ok so the worksheet name is different from the file name I got it. The worksheet name in all my files are Values because I run a script to convert TDMS files into XLSX files and I strip the first sheets and only keep the sheets where all the datas are stored. The data in column A (time) are stored in this format "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss,zzz" but it's not a date it is saved like this in text format directly in the TDMS file

Comment: No I still have the problem. I have changed the line and still have a problem. Worksheets(Ws.Name).Columns("A").Replace    I have error 424 Object required

Comment: When I add a worksheet variable : Dim Ws As Worksheet     I got the error 91 "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: When I replace ws.name by "Values" I got Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Comment: @gamer388.  I have added a new section to my answer.  I hope this will give you a better understanding of what is happening and help you diagnose the cause of your problem.

Comment: OK I have posted my answer below yours because it seems to replace the dot fine now but the format of the cell in Excel is not correct (different from when I use CTRL + H manually to replace the comma by dot in column A)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I tried what you said and it worked.
At first it replace all my data in column A by *.* I removed the "*" character and seems to be better now.

But it's still not doing what CTRL+H is doing to my data (preserving the formatting).
I'll include screenshots so it's easier to understand what is happening.

The file looks like this (original untouched converted TDMS to XLSX) :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiB1P.jpg

If I use CTRL+ H to find and replace "," by "." I got the good formatting :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSmGk.jpg

When I run my VBA script, I don't get the same output :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MCNn.jpg

It seems like Excel is interpreting the data as a Date after the VBA script is run.
All I want is just a way to have the same output as if I used the CTRL + H hotkey to replace all the comma by dot in column A.

And no I don't have a prompt about overwritting file when using the saveas command maybe because I used display.alerts = false.

The VBA code I'm using now :

```
Sub ReplaceCommabyDot_folder()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim InputFile As Variant
Dim InputFolder As String, OutputFolder As String, myfile As String
Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim Ws As Worksheet

InputFolder = "D:\Downloads\01_PT-Major_Proto-174_cycle-by-cycle\cycle-2\data"
OutputFolder = "D:\Downloads\01_PT-Major_Proto-174_cycle-by-cycle\cycle-2\data"

'Loop through each csv file in source folder
InputFile = Dir(InputFolder & "\*.xlsx")

While InputFile <> ""
    myfile = InputFolder & "\" & InputFile
    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(myfile)
    'Set Ws = Worksheets("Values")
    wbSource.Worksheets("Values").Columns("A").Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

'Save each output file in output folder
wbSource.SaveAs Filename:=myfile, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault, local:=True
Workbooks(InputFile).Close

InputFile = Dir
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: I have added a further section to my answer which might help.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help Tony. But it seems to not hold the last digit after the dot when the comma is replaced by dot. Strange because a simple CTRL + H with "," and "." works fine. It seems impossible to reproduce this behavior with VBA. Wonder why cause the VBA to not behave like when I manually select and use XTRL + H to replace comma by dot in column A. Maybe if we force Excel to use string formatting in column A it will work the same as CTRL + H.

Comment: Please read my second edit carefully.  "But it seems to not hold the last digit after the dot when the comma is replaced by dot."  This is incorrect.  Excel will **hold** a date to three decimal digits but it will not **display** to three decimal digits.  I believe both your sets of values are strings.  If Excel had recognised the changed value as a date, it would have changed the display.

Comment: Yeah I read carefully the first time. I tried myself to format to  .NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss.000" but Excel seems to doesn't care. I don't understand why Excel can do it with CTRL + H but not when using VBA to automate the process. Like WTF is this. It's getting me nuts. Thanks for your help Tony it was really appreciated.